# How do I fix this malloc() error in C++ when I am trying to load a kernel module?

Tags: c++, malloc

I am getting the error `malloc(): memory corruption` when I execute this code in C++. Basically, I open a kernel file and I use malloc with the size of `struct stat st`. I guess this is causing the problem.

The code loads a kernel module (I2C) and it is actually loading. but I guess I am not using the `malloc()` as should be used. Thanks.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

#define init_module(mod, len, opts) syscall(__NR_init_module, mod, len, opts)
#define delete_module(name, flags) syscall(__NR_delete_module, name, flags)
class I2CKernelModule : public testing::Test {
public:
    I2CKernelModule() {
    }
};
TEST_F(I2CKernelModule, TestAddAndRemoveKernelModule) {
    char *params;
    int fd;
    size_t image_size;
    struct stat st;
    void *image;

    // command: sudo insmod /root/i2c-tests/i2c-stub.ko chip_addr=0x20
    params = "chip_addr=0x20";
    fd = open("/root/i2c-tests/i2c-stub.ko", O_RDONLY);
    fstat(fd, &st);
    image_size = st.st_size;
    image = malloc(image_size);
    read(fd, image, image_size);
    close(fd);
    if (init_module(image, image_size, params) != 0) {
        perror("init_module");
        GTEST_FAIL();
    }
    free(image);
    GTEST_SUCCESS_("Kernel module loaded.");

    /*
    // sudo rmmod i2c_stub
    if (delete_module("i2c_stub", O_NONBLOCK) != 0) {
        perror("delete_module");
        GTEST_FAIL();
    }
    GTEST_SUCCESS_("Kernel module unloaded.");
    */
}
```

Comment: *Why* are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?

Comment: Add diagnostics. Printf the value of `fd` after the call to `open`. Print the value of `image_size`. Print the return value from `read`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl There's no C++ in it anywhere. It is really a C program.

Comment: @ZanLynx Agreed. But OP claims C++ so I assume it's compiled with a C++ compiler. And the question is tagged "c++" as well. And if it is supposed to be treated as C++ then `malloc` is a strange choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return values of all functions for errors. The code you have listed would fail if the file doesn't open, the stat fails or the malloc fails. It is also a good idea to check the number of bytes returned by read.

Comment: Should this not have been a comment?

Comment: No because this literally is how he fixes his error.